# Use List and Map Fragments in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to understand now Android Fragments and looking for working tutorials. I would like to use a list and map in the same activity if they are fragments. 
I understand that each fragment has it's own life cycle and to think of them as an activity. My interest is in the flow that i have to follow to make this work. I should create a class that extends ListFragment and one that extends FragmentActivity(if i didn't get it wrong, it contains a MapFragment) and then on class that extends Activity and somehow calls and adds those fragments to the activity? What content view will i have in the Activity class, thinking that in the fragments classes i will have an xml for each.
I am confuzed at the moment and tried some tutorials that did not work and looking for one example that does what it says it will do, please.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing maps (google maps) and Fragments is not very straightforward, speccially if you're targetting not only tablets but also smartphones using the android compatiblity library, so if you can avoid it, use a simple MapActivity , otherwise I recommend taking a look at ActionBarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: My target is only tablets. So you suggest not using fragments concerning list and map all in the same place?

Comment: If your target is only tablets things should be easier. First be sure to set your target to android 3.0 or higher, then create your activity extending MapActivity. I suggest you put a mapview directly inside the layout for your activity and then put also a fragment (or a container foru your fragment using a framelayout) to hold a ListFragment

Comment: do you have please a peace of code, i am facing the same problem and i can't found a solution